# ErrorException in BladeCompiler.php line 584: Undefined offset: 1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I'm learning Laravel and now I have faced a bad problem. Basically I have added a new controller called `UsersController.php` and I have set the route to that controller inside of `web.php`. Here's the controller:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users = [
            '0' => [
                'first_name' => 'Renato',
                'last_name' => 'Hysa',
                'location' => 'Albania'
            ],
            '1' => [
                'first_name' => 'Jessica',
                'last_name' => 'Alba',
                'location' => 'USA'
            ]
        ];
        return view('admin.users.index', compact('users'));
    }
}
```

So as you can see I have linked this to a blade which is inside of resources/views/admin/users and it is called `index.blade.php` and goes like this:

```
 @foreach($users as $user)
    <li>
    {!! $user['first_name'] !!} {!! $user['last_name'] !!}
    from {!! $user['location'] !!}
    </li>
@foreach
```

So when I goto this URL it must shows the users but instead of that it shows an error:

**ErrorException in BladeCompiler.php line 584:
Undefined offset: 1**

*Click to see the [print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULV2B.png) of my page*

And unfortunately I know nothing about what's going on there. I'm pretty sure that I have added everything correctly because I'm following a Youtube tutorials playlist and you can goto this [link](https://youtu.be/U_2YqbvrANA?list=PL3ZhWMazGi9IYymniZgqwnYuPFDvaEHJb&t=409) to see how it should be shown on the browser.

So if you know whats going wrong here please let me know.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `index.blade.php` code need to update like:

```
 @foreach($users as $user)
   <li>
   {!! $user['first_name'] !!} {!! $user['last_name'] !!}
   from {!! $user['location'] !!}
   </li>
@endforeach
```

Hope this work for you!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 @foreach($users as $user)
<li>
{{ $user['first_name'] }} {{ $user['last_name'] }}
from {{ $user['location'] }}
</li>
@foreach
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($users as $user)
<li>
{!! $user['first_name'] !!} {!! $user['last_name'] !!}
from {!! $user['location'] !!}
</li>
```

@endforeach

The problem was ***endforeach***